# MS Visual Studio 2010 C++ Preprocessor - If function is defined in macro with calls elsewhere, is there any overhead hit when undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a quick question, which I am sure has been asked so I do apologize if it is a duplicate. I tried searching google and stackoverflow but the results were unrelated to my question.

The scenario:

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project configuration that defines a preprocessor named DBG.
In the code, I have a #ifdef DBG section that declares a function signature in the header file (let's call it writeToFile) and defines that function within another #ifdef DBG/#endif section in the cpp file.
Throughout the rest of the project are calls to writeToFile.

The questions:

When the project is compiled under a different configuration (one that doesn't define DBG), how is this handled by the compiler? I know that the portions within the #ifdef/endif directives are pretty much ignored, but what happens to all the function calls to writeToFile? Does the compiler ignore these, too? Or during run time, do these calls actually occur and do nothing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consult your favorite C language book, there are many and K&R is thin, about the way the preprocessor works.  Any text that's inside an #ifdef that doesn't match is completely removed.  Before the compiler can see the source code.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question is what happens to the code outside of the #ifdef/#endif (function calls to function defined conditionally) when there is no match.

Comment: Clearly you ought to expect one of: a) loud bang, b) white smoke billowing from your machine, c) error messages in the Error List window.  c) is most likely.

Comment: As stated below, no errors or problems. I have done it like this for 2 years. I was just wondering today what happens under the hood ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the compiler should throw an error (undefined function `writeToFile()`). But you should be able to battle this by specifying `#else` section that defines the same function with an empty body. ie.

```
#ifdef DBG
  void fun() { cout << "hello"; }
#else
  void fun() { };
#endif //DBG
```

**EDIT:**
I personally would just define the function you want, and put the `#ifdef/#endif` block inside it's body.

Comment: Oddly, the compiler doesn't throw an error so I am wondering how the compiler is handling it ... I did define the function within the #ifdef/#endif ...

Comment: Can you step inside the function using debuger? Is it possible that there is another function of the same name?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a plugin dll to another process that I don't have control of and the debugger does not work. This is why I have this conditional function in the first place (I am logging to file in the debug project). I don't think there is another function with the same name, in fact, I can change the function name and the same thing happens ...